# How to fix this corroded zipper?

Tags: repair

This is more general repair than home DIY, hopefully right place for it.

I tried getting something out of a snowboard bag and found it was sealed by corroded zippers. I'm not sure why this happened as I've stored it like I have for years: off the floor in a dry-ish garage. Here are photos:

[image: zipper 1]

[image: zipper 2]

The zippers barely budge, and I applied a decent amount of force to the zipper pulling the zipper and bag away from each other almost parallel to the zipper track. I'm considering using plyers and pulling much harder, and I wondered about first cleaning the corrosion with vinegar or using a lubricant. I figured I'd get some better informed opinions first.

How can I get this zipper back in working order? Less important, I wonder how this happened in the first place and how to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Any drain cleaner or other harsh chemical that could have leaked in the garage?  Some vapors are _highly_ corrosive but can disappear without a trace.

Comment: Also, those nylon zippers can be forced open by stabbing the center of the zipper with a ball point pen or similarly shaped object anywhere along its length.  The zipper is normally not damaged and will pull right open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start out with some club soda since it's pretty good at acidic materials. If it doesn't work then try some vinegar. work the zipper back and forth to free it up and then squirt some WD-40 on it. You mentioned it is a snowboard bag. You might have accumulated some salt from roadways on the bag and it froze up the zipper. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I would use steamer gun. Before hand if the corrosion is thick or formed as crystals use a needle to remove at the joints first. Or dampen it first. Let the steamer heat reach the inner part of the zipper. Heat helps to break them apart then try pulling as per normal.

It worked for me on a 33 inch dive travel bag.